Distortion of the model due to being too far from the origin
I created a world map with the world origin at the geographic longitude and latitude origin
At this point, I placed a robot in the Chinese region, but the robot was distorted; But when I place the robot at the origin of the world, it can display normally
world map
Distorted robots
I want to know why robots are distorted

Does this answer your question? Three.js SkinnedMesh jitter when far from scene root (0,0,0) on IOS

I think it's feasible to always keep the model to be displayed near the origin! I have tried this before, but I want to understand why anomalies occur when the distance from the origin is too far. Not only the model, but also the lines that cause shaking when slightly rotating the perspective! Can you give me an answer? Thank you

The cause is floating point error, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/1314762. Precision is limited in JavaScript, in WebGL shaders it's even more limited -- the larger your numbers, the larger the potential errors.

Thank you for your answer, but I'm not too sure；
I adjusted the size of the world grid to 400x398 by modifying the coordinate size output during geoJSON conversion, and then placed the robot on it, which looked normal;
But if I scale down the robot to a certain proportion, there will still be distortion, or tearing; Is this also caused by too many decimal places in floating-point numbers

That could also be floating point precision, yes. You'd need to post a demo to get a full confirmation on that. Also make sure that your camera's .near and .far distances are set to fit the visible scene, if they're two far apart you'll see similar issues.
